# ExtJs3: how to make closable tab of tabpanel not closable and back?

Tags: dynamic, extjs, tabs, tabpanel

I want to be able to hide 'x' button near the tab title and to be able to show it back without a low level code manipulating DOM but using component level api functions if it is possible.

Comment: The idea of "meeting our quality standards" by requirering a certain amount of text, is to get you to thoroughly explain what it is you want to do. Use text, images where you visualize what you want, code examples explaining how you have tried to solve your problem before you asked your question here, and so on...

Comment: i think its not possible without manipulating DOM ... but you can remove the tab and add it with the new closeable:true/false parameter at the same position. but this sollution look and feels bad ;-)

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution but it is really-really bad. Another way is to actually hide this 'x' element and I actually know how but... I always try to avoid low level programming and had a hope that there is some other way to do it... using for example parent layout or something like that.

Comment: and when you make the tab closeable:false by default and insert a tbar with close icon? such icon you can easily show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually hide the close button in the DOM.

I tested this code over ExtJS 3 API page. It toggles close button on the second tab:

```
var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('doc-body');
var tabHeader = tabPanel.items.get(1).tabEl;
Ext.get(tabHeader).down('a.x-tab-strip-close').toggleClass('x-hidden')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems that this is the best solution.